# Instructions interchanged?

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Are the instructions to the following problem interchanged, or am I wrong?

> Problem: Let $(\mathbb{R}^2,d)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2,d')$ be two metric spaces, with $d(P,R)=\sqrt{(x_P-x_R)^2+(y_P-y_R)^2}$ and
> $$
>   d'(P,R) =
> \begin{cases}
> 0,  & P=R, \\
> 1, & P \neq R.
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Suppose $i_d$ denotes the identity function.
> a) Prove that $i_d:(\mathbb{R}^2,d) \to (\mathbb{R}^2,d')$ is continuous. 
> b) Prove that $i_d:(\mathbb{R}^2,d') \to (\mathbb{R}^2,d)$ is not continuous.

Disproof of **a)**:

Suppose $i_d$, defined as such, is continuous. Now let $\epsilon=1/2$, and $P,R \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then for $d'(i_d(P),i_d(R))<\epsilon=1/2$, we would need $P=R$, otherwise $d'(i_d(P),i_d(R))=1$. But there is no $\delta>0$ to guarantee $d(P,R)<\delta$ and thereby   $P=R$, which is needed in the consequent to warrant $d'(i_d(P),i_d(R))<\epsilon$. $\blacksquare$

Disproof of **b)**:

The function $i_d$ is continuous. Let $P \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\epsilon>0$. Now let $\delta=1/2$ and  $R \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $d'(P,R)<\delta$. Then clearly $P=R$, so $d(i_d(P),i_d(R))=0<\epsilon$.  $\blacksquare$

Comment: Continuity preserves connectedness.  In (a), the map takes a connected set to a disconnected set, so it can't be continuous.  So yes, (a) is incorrect.  For (b), the topology induced by the discrete metric is the powerset---every set is open.  The preimage of an open ball with respect to $d$ is therefore open, hence the map from $(\mathbb{R}^2,d')$ to $(\mathbb{R}^2, d)$ is continuous.  So (b) is wrong as well.  It seems that yes, indeed, the instructions were reversed.

Comment: Thank you. I now have a more visual understanding.